# Brackets highlighting doesn't work correctly - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, syntax-highlighting

I am working on creating an text editor for my own programming language. It works just fine, but I have one problem; When I enter something like this:

```
void Example() {
   for (int i = 0, 10; i++) {
    console.println(i);
   }
}
```

The closing bracket of the for-loop

```
for (int i = 0, 10; i++) {
    console.println(i);
} <== This one
```

isn't highlighted. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Color
Imports System.Drawing.Font

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Highlight(ByRef Text As String(), ByRef Name As String)
    Dim Color As Color = Nothing
    Dim Font As Font = Nothing
    Select Case Name
        Case "Keywords"
            Color = Blue
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
        Case "Functions"
            Color = Black
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Italic)
        Case "Classes"
            Color = Cyan
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
        Case "Types"
            Color = Purple
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
        Case "Operators"
            Color = GreenYellow
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
        Case "Brackets"
            Color = Red
            Font = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
    End Select
    Dim CursorPos As Integer = tb.SelectionStart
    For i As Integer = 0 To Text.Length - 1
        FindAll(tb, Text(i))
        tb.SelectionColor = Color
        tb.SelectionFont = Font
        tb.DeselectAll()
    Next
    tb.SelectionStart = CursorPos
    tb.SelectionColor = Nothing
    tb.SelectionFont = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
End Sub

Private Function NewFont(ByVal Style As FontStyle)
    Return New Font(tb.Font, Style)
End Function

Private Sub FindAll(ByRef tb As RichTextBox, ByRef Find As String)
    Dim StartIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim Text As String = tb.Text
    Do
        Dim Index As Integer = Text.IndexOf(Find, StartIndex)
        If Index < 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        tb.Select(Index, Find.Length)
        StartIndex = Index + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tb.TextChanged
    Dim Keywords As String() = {"new", "using", "void", "function", "public", "protected", "private", "if", "else", "for", "loop", "while", "until", "true", "false", "null", "default"}
    Dim Types As String() = {"string", "int", "long", "byte", "char"}
    Dim Brackets As String() = {"(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}"}
    Dim Operators As String() = {"+", "-", "=", "/", "*"}
    Dim Classes As String() = {"console", "color", "font"}
    Dim Functions As String() = {"print", "println"}
    Highlight(Keywords, "Keywords")
    Highlight(Types, "Types")
    Highlight(Brackets, "Brackets")
    Highlight(Operators, "Operators")
    Highlight(Classes, "Classes")
    Highlight(Functions, "Functions")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should move the arrays out of the `TextChanged` event (or at least set them to `Static`). Declaring new ones every time is a waste of memory.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. The bracket is still non-highlighted.

Comment: I didn't say it was the solution. But it will decrease memory usage and may increase the speed a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is only highliting the last occurence of each bracket, operator, etc...

By applying the font and color after each successful find will effect the text properly.

BTW-your code doesn't un-hilite keyword (e.g. **void** changed to **vo id** stays hilited)

**The Outcome** tadaa

[image]

Modify the **FindAll()** procedure

```
    Private Sub FindAll(ByRef tb As RichTextBox, ByRef Find As String, ByRef StartIndex As Integer)

    Dim Text As String = tb.Text

    Dim Index As Integer = Text.IndexOf(Find, StartIndex)
    StartIndex = Index + 1
    If Index < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    tb.Select(Index, Find.Length)
End Sub
```

and the **For loop** at the end of the **Highlight** procedure

```
        Dim CursorPos As Integer = tb.SelectionStart

    For i As Integer = 0 To Text.Length - 1
        Dim StartIndex As Integer = 0
        Do
            FindAll(tb, Text(i), StartIndex)

            If StartIndex = 0 Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            tb.SelectionColor = Color
            tb.SelectionFont = Font
            tb.DeselectAll()
        Loop
        tb.SelectionStart = CursorPos
        tb.SelectionColor = Nothing
        tb.SelectionFont = NewFont(FontStyle.Regular)
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! But, **vo id** is still highlighted.

Comment: @HighTechProgramming15: Go for it. Your doing fine